# Storage has a few files but Firestore Bandwidth too much

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a social media app with video sharing. When a user uploads a video I upload the video to storage and save the downloadurl to my database. When the feed loads I simply fetch the urls from the database and play the videos. I do not have much data in my storage however my bandwidth is too high. How do I minimize usage?

For the profile pictures I have made a NSCache but i do not know how to reduce the bandwidth. Should I only fetch new posts? How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Firebase Authentication and realtime-database to manage this.

1. Go to firebase at https://console.firebase.google.com/ and create a new project.
2. Once created, Add your android/iOS app and enter your app package name.
3. Give your app a nickname.
4. enter your app's SHA-1 certificate key.
5. Download the config file and put it in your root directory of app.
6. Add all the firebase SDK's in your gradle file, It will look like this:
   (("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.2/firebase.js"))
7. Your app is connected. Just skip the confirmation step in firebase,It doesn't matter.
8. Go into the Database tab and scroll down...There you will find "Realtime-Database", Open It.
9. Start it in test mode
10. Then go to the authentication tab and go to the "signup methods".
11. From there, enable Email/Password authentication or any other type of authentication you like.
12. Go to the storage tab and enable it.
13. Then see this to enable Authentication:
    If you are making an android app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start OR
    if you are making an iOS app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start.
14. Then set up realtime-database:
    If you are making an android app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start OR
    if you are making an iOS app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write.
15. Then set up storage:
    If you are making an android app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start OR
    if you are making an iOS app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/create-reference.

    ------------THE STEPS WILL MOSTLY BE THE SAME ON BOTH DEVICES-----------------------------
    ------------IF YOU ARE HAVING TROUBLE CONNECTING AN iOS APP THEN VISIT: ------------------
    ------------ https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup ----------------------------------